# Does AngularJS reuse watchers?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
    {{ item.name }}
</div>

<div ng-repeat="item in items">
    {{ item.name }} - {{ item.number}}
</div>
```

In this example, does AngularJS reuse watchers for `items`, `item` and `item.name` or does it register new watchers even if it's actually "physically" the same object or property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will register new watchers. However, if you have reason to know that these values will not be changing once they're set you can help inform AngularJS of this with a new option in 1.3.x (1.3.14 and higher, I think):

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
    {{ :: item.name }}
</div>
```

This will create a short-lived watcher that waits until the value of item.name "settles" (becomes a real value and doesn't change for one digest). After that you won't have a watcher anymore. This is great for things like message lists that aren't going to change unless you yourself trigger it by adding/removing items.

Comment: However, the expression in `ng-repeat` will still be watched anyway.